# OCaml - can someone explain this "pattern-matching is not exhaustive"

Tags: ocaml

So I have this piece of code:

```
let rec minBound s =
    match s with
    Rect (s,i)-> Rect(s,i)
    |Circle (c,r)-> getRectOutCircle (c,r)
    |Union(l,r)-> 
        let Rect(sl, il) = (minBound l) in
        let Rect(sr, ir) = (minBound r) in
        let (xsl,ysl) = sl in 
        let (xil,yil) = il in
        let (xsr,ysr) = sr in   
        let (xir,yir) = ir in           
        Rect( ((min xsl xsr), (min ysl ysr)) , 
              (( max xil xir), (max yil yir)) )
    |Intersection(l,r)-> 
        let Rect(sl, il) = (minBound l) in
        let Rect(sr, ir) = (minBound r) in
        let (xsl,ysl) = sl in 
        let (xil,yil) = il in
        let (xsr,ysr) = sr in   
        let (xir,yir) = ir in           
        Rect( ((min xsl xsr), (min ysl ysr)) , 
              (( max xil xir), (max yil yir)) )
    |Subtraction(l,r) -> 
        let Rect(sl, il) = (minBound l) in
        let Rect(sr, ir) = (minBound r) in 
        let (xsl,ysl) = sl in   
        let (xil,yil) = il in           
        let (xsr,ysr) = sr in                   
        let (xir,yir) = ir in
        Rect( ((min xsl xsr), (min ysl ysr)) , 
              (( max xil xir), (max yil yir)) )                 
;;
```

Can someone explain why is this giving me the following warning?

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
(Circle (_, _)|Union (_, _)|Intersection (_, _)|Subtraction (_, _))val minBound : shape -> shape = <fun>
```

Here is some more info to help!!

```
type point = float*float;;

type shape = Rect of point*point
       | Circle of point*float
       | Union of shape*shape
       | Intersection of shape*shape
       | Subtraction of shape*shape
;;
```

Comment: How about removing all the code except the pattern matching? Just have the function return unit and see if the problems persists.

Comment: Well, somebody undid all my work of formatting the code for readability. I'm not going to redo it, sorry.

Comment: However, in the future please post code that is readable.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield You have the power to roll back edits on any post. But then so does the owner and anyone else with enough rep of course. If a rollback fight ensues, just call a moderator.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the info. Life's too short to worry about this too much I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `minBound` returns type `shape`. But your recursive calls assume that it can return only one kind of shape. The compiler is warning you that it could return shapes of the other kinds.

This is a common problem. Basically you know that `minBound` always returns a `Rect`, but the compiler doesn't know it.

One possible solution would be to have `minBound` return `point * point`.

Comment: but it is supposed to return always a Rect, how do I correct it?

Comment: You could write a helper function that translates Rect (...) to point * point, while raising an exception for all other shapes.

Comment: Or more cleanly, a wrapper arround `minBound` that adds a Rect after all the calculations have been done and you want to use the result with other `shape` values.

Comment: it is done, thanks for your help, that was exactly the problem